# How to install npm devdependencies recursively?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am working on a project which gives cli options to another project. **The cli requires some extra dependency which I had listed as devdependency**. However, when installed on the target project, the devdependency are not being installed.

`npm install` : Installs first level of dev dependency but the dev dependency of a dependency is not installed.

[There used to be an option](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5554) but it was actually a bug and therefore removed. Is there a way to do this now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dependency is required by the target project that is installing it, it should be listed as a dependency.  DevDependencies are intended for use only when the module itself is being developed (eg test and packaging tools. )

Answer (score 1):

do `npm install --only=dev` this will install dev-dependencies of all dependencies in package.json if you want to install dev-dependencies for just one package do dev-dependencies `npm install <package> --only=dev`

Comment: Check the link in my question. This was the earlier behavior but it was "corrected" to only install first level dependency.

Comment: **The cli requires some extra dependency which I had listed as devdependency**,  you should just fix the package.json then and move it to dependencies